# How to trigger a Vimperator command after manually openning a new tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, vimperator

I've been using Vimperator for some time and I'm really happy with it but there is a break in my workflow which bothers me:

Sometimes I open a new tab "manually" i.e. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or even by clicking on the `+` sign next to the last tab. I know I can open a new tab with `:tabopen` and I created a convenient mapping for that but sometimes I just don't use it.

**My problem is the following:** I set `set gui=nonavigation` in my `.vimperatorrc` so when I open a tab "manually" if I forget to type `o` to trigger the command line with the `open` command and instead directly type the url I get unexpected results since the keys I type as a url are simply considered as vimperator input.

**So my question is:** Is it possible to trigger a vimperator command after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or clicking the `+` sign? The idea would be to automatically type `o` after those two events so I'm directly in the command line with the `open` command to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pentadactyl: General Solution

This solution works in Pentadactyl (which I'll include here since Pentadactyl falls under the Vimperator tag on SO).

It *should* work on Vimperator as well, but doesn't (at least on my version), since Vimperator is hopelessly buggy. It should be possible to work around the bugs, but I didn't find a way when I tried it.

Anyway, the right way to do this is with an autocommand, which will execute whenever an `about:newtab` url is loaded.

- begin `:open` command when *loading* a new tab page:

  ```
  autocmd PageLoadPre about:newtab normal o
  ```
- begin `:open` command when *loading or changing to* a new tab page:

  ```
  autocmd LocationChange about:newtab normal o
  ```

Comment: Really great answer thank you very much! To be honest I had forgotten about this question but I'm glad you give me a good way to do that. Also just because I'm curious can you explain why the autocmd is triggered when a new tab is opened (`CTRL+t` or `+` sign) but isn't when I use `:winopen`? That seems strange to me because `:winopen` opens a window with a `about:newtab` in it.

Comment: @statox: I'm not sure why that's happening. Probably something to do with window-local variables. In my Pentadactyl, the autocommand works in the new window, but not when the first tab is launched, so you could get the right behaviour using the command `:winopen | open about:newtab`. You could map that to a key or a new command (You're not allowed to redefine built-in commands, although you could probably get around that with JS if you track down the data structure mapping command names to commands.)

Comment: I think the idea of defining a new command is pretty good actually. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since when I wrote this question I changed of plugin and now use pentadactyl instead of vimperator but I have solved the problem with the following mapping which should work with both:

```
nmap <C-t> :tabopen<CR>o
```

This way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will open the new tab and trigger the `:open` command.

This is not a perfect solution since it doesn't work with tabs opened with the `+` sign but its a workaround.